# how this kind of syntax is even possible

Tags: java, syntax

Ive just noticed this kind of syntax:

```
 System.out.<String>println("...");
```

If we look at method println:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Its not parametrized, so how complier dont give a warning? Thx for your time

Comment: The "x" you are printing should now be a string even if it was an integer?

Comment: It seems like you can actually put *any* class name in the brackets.

Comment: it doesnt matter, ye

Comment: You're allowed to do that but the type argument will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code makes no sense and of course has to not be used as whatever the generic type you specify, it has the same effect : nothing but a warning at compile time explaining that the type argument is not used as the method is not generic.